# prove that the gcd of two given numbers is 1

Tags: number-theory

Is there something am missing here?

Prove that gcd$(11k + 7, 5k + 3) = 1.$  for some $k = 1,2,3,....N$

when I try $k = 3$ for example:

gcd$(40,18)$ is $2\ne1$.

Comment: You are asked to show that the $\gcd$ equals $1$ for *some* $k$. Not necessarily for *every* $k$.

Comment: For some $k=1,2,3,\cdots,N$?

Answer (score 3):

If integer $d$ divides both $11k+7,5k+3$

$d$ must divide $5(11k+7)-11(5k+3)=2$

Now $11k+7\equiv k+1\pmod2$ and $5k+3\equiv k+1$

So, $(11k+7,5k+3)=2$ iff $k+1$ is even

else $(11k+7,5k+3)=1$